# Group and sort the query results based on a parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

```
id   | myid | timestamp
---------------------------------
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-15 12:10:52  
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-14 12:10:52  
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52  
1002  | 2     | 2021-03-15 11:10:52  
1002  | 2     | 2021-03-16 10:10:52    
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52    
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-10 12:10:52    
1004  | 4     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52  
1004  | 4     | 2021-03-16 12:17:52    
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-12 12:10:52    
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-11 12:18:52
```

This is my db table in mysql and I have many other columns in this table. I want to get all the rows where myid=1. The results should be grouped based on the id and sorted by timestamp. The query should limit the group of ids based on a parameter

Expected result when limit is 3

```
id   | myid | timestamp
---------------------------------
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52    
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-10 12:10:52  
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-12 12:10:52    
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-11 12:18:52
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52 
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-15 12:10:52   
1001  | 1     | 2021-03-14 12:10:52
```

Expected result when limit is 2

```
id   | myid | timestamp
---------------------------------
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-16 12:10:52    
1005  | 1     | 2021-03-10 12:10:52  
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-12 12:10:52    
1003  | 1     | 2021-03-11 12:18:52
```

Comment: you mention that "results should be grouped based on the id and sorted by timestamp" but the result you showing is not sorted by timestamp.

Comment: Yes, timestamp is sorted in the descending order

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) cnt
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE myid = 1
)

-- for groups of 3
SELECT id, myid, timestamp
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 3
ORDER BY id DESC, timestamp DESC;

-- for groups of 2
SELECT id, myid, timestamp
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 2
ORDER BY id DESC, timestamp DESC;
```

### Demo

Comment: This looks great. Thanks Tim. Can you send me a single query to get the results as i need to convert the query to JOOQ to use within my application

Comment: Just inline the CTE into the query, that's all.  Are you using MySQL 8+?

Comment: No :( . I am using mysql 5.7

Comment: Then you can't use my answer, and it will be fairly difficult to achieve your output on MySQL 5.7.  I suggest upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.id, t2.myid
       FROM test t2
       WHERE t2.myid = @myid
       GROUP BY t2.id, t2.myid
       HAVING COUNT(*) <= @mycount ) t3 USING (id, myid);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3279e16f33cf39d2a5483eca6e2137cd

PS. Add ORDER BY as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by myid order by min_timeastamp, id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(timestamp) over (partition by myid, id) as min_timestamp
            from t
            where myid = 1
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

This enumerates each group of `id` by the minimum timestamp and then uses that for determining which groups to return.